# Can get id from clicked class, but not class from clicked id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the jsfiddle for what I was testing http://jsfiddle.net/5hhRF/

there is number 1 2 1 2.... when u click last digit which is "2" it don't alert.

Was I missing some code for that case?

I am copying the same code here again.

```
<span class="open-option" id="option1" >1</span>
<span class="open-option" id="option2" >2</span>

<span id="open-option" class="option1" >1</span>
<span id="open-option" class="option2" >2</span>​
```

```
    $(".open-option").click(function(){                    
       var myID=$(this).attr('id'); 
       alert(myID);
    });

    $("#open-option").click(function(){                    
       var myClass=$(this).attr('class'); 
       alert(myClass);
    });


                        ​
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you for all the answer( which r mostly same ). I thought "(this)" can uniquely identify the clicked id. My fault assumption :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`click` event is binding only to **first** element with given id.

ID's in the page must be unique.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign the same id to multiple elements.

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/attrs.html

> The ID attribute uniquely identifies an element within a document. No
>   two elements can have the same ID value in a single document.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` `id` `selector` return an array but contains only 1st elements in `DOM`  with the id. So here in your code the `click handler is being applied to 1st DOM elements only`

you can make use of [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("span[id*='open-option']").click(function(){                    
   var myClass=$(this).attr('class');
   alert(myClass);
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5hhRF/4/

Comment: Although I accepted the fact that ID should be unique so I will follow that. But thank you very much for the hacked code. Can u plz link me to the DOC for better understanding for the kind of selector u use. span[id^='. Thanks Again :D

Comment: u should actully accept this answer because its not oly telling u the reason but also giving u the alternative solution lollzzz... anyway u r most welcome.. u can find it http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs must be unique, I'm afraid, as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/902843/339852). Otherwise, your code simply won't work.