# Jquery detect keypress in multiple inputs with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a bunch of input boxes with the same id but different names like so:

```
<input type="text" id="description" name="1">
<input type="text" id="description" name="2">
<input type="text" id="description" name="3">
```

Now for a single input box (only one box uses the id) I use:

```
$('#description').keypress(function(....
```

What I would ideally like to be able to do is use the above function and then do something based on the name of the input box but for multiple input boxes to carry the same id. Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Please avoid same id for multiple inputs id is identifier make that to appear only one time in your page you can use class for this purpose

Comment: I changed the id into class but still doesn't work

Comment: If not necessary then change the id of the text box make it unique

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery select divs with same id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902839/jquery-select-divs-with-same-id)

Answer (score 5):

You should have unique id for html elements you should assign a common class and access throug it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQP9D/1/)**

```
<input type="text" id="description1" name="1" class="commonclass">
<input type="text" id="description2" name="2" class="commonclass">
<input type="text" id="description3" name="3" class="commonclass">


 $('.commonclass').keypress(function(event){
       alert("keycode: " + event.keyCode);
       alert("id: " + this.id);
 });​
```

Comment: That didn't work, it still doesn't detect keypress from an input box with more having the same class :/

Comment: It should work. Maybe your handler function isn't writtent correctly (it needs to use `$(this)` to reference the current input box).

Answer (score 0):

Apply class name to multiple elements. Then use jquery with class to handle keypress event.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit late for my answer, but in case someone else stumbles upon this question here.

For me the problem was solved by wrapping the code in the document ready event.
This ensures the input controls exist in the DOM at the time the events are attached.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.commonclass').keypress(function(event){
    alert("keycode: " + event.keyCode);
    alert("id: " + this.id);
  });​
});
```