# An alternative way to execute keypress() for multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jquery input objects, called $input1 and $input2, that I want to bind a keypress() method to,

Either I can do this:

```
    $($input1).add($input2).keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            $button.click();
        }
    });
```

or write individual functions for each of the two $input objects. Is there a way to make something like this work instead?

```
    $($input1, $input2).keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            $button.click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: That works fine. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: I can only make it work with the .add()  function; I want to know why the second way ($($input1, $input2)) doesn't work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e4898gos/

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class to both inputs and all elements that have that class will detect keypress.

the approach is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447857/jquery-detect-keypress-in-multiple-inputs-with-same-id)