# jQuery function run just in first row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I already fetched all values from database into table

```
foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    ?>
<form method="post">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" id="edit-btn">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<div class="edit-box1">
   <input id="idd" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $idd; ?>" name="status111">
   <input type="submit" value="GO" name="edit-go">
</div>
</tr>
</form>
}
```

And this is the jQuery code:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery("#edit-btn").click(function() {
            jQuery("#idd").prop("readonly", false);
        });
    });
```

The problem is that I got 20 rows and my edit button just run on my first row.

How can I make my jQuery run on all rows ?

Comment: you have to add the different ids for all rows
or you can select the rows from adding the class as well

Comment: for example let me give you the full code. in answer

Comment: How can i add diffrerent ids on each rows even it fetched data from database

Comment: okey But please guide me too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select all elements with a particular ID in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902839/how-to-select-all-elements-with-a-particular-id-in-jquery)

Comment: $( "#idd" ).each(function() {   jQuery("#idd").prop("readonly", false);    });

Comment: added the solution hope it will work.

Comment: The markup is totally invalid. `<tr>`s without a `<table>` (or a `<form/>` anywhere in a `<table/>`) and `<div />`s without an enclosing `<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be your HTML

```
$cnt=0;
foreach ( $result as $print )   {
?>
    <form method="post">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="edit-button" id='<?php echo $cnt;?>'>Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <div class="edit-box1">
            <input id="idd<?php echo $cnt;?>" type="text"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $idd; ?>" name="status111">
            <input type="submit" value="GO" name="edit-go">
            <?php $cnt++; ?>
        </div>
        </tr>
     </form>
}
```

This will be your jquery code

```
<script>

   jQuery(document).ready(
       function() {
           jQuery(".edit-button").click(function() {
           jQuery("#idd"+$(this).attr("id")).prop("readonly", false);
       });
   });
</script>
```

Hope this will work surely.

Comment: is it okey now ? @Andreas

Comment: now this is final editing it should have no issue.@Andreas

Comment: Sir The problem is when i use inspect element it show me id="0" in all rows

Comment: have you copied the `<?php $cnt++; ?>` @Hammad

Comment: oh sorry i just forgot to declare $cnt before the for loop @Hammad

Comment: Yup Sir I paste it after div also but nothing happened

Comment: Code Work Successfull :) :) :)

Comment: <a href="#" class="edit-button" id='<?php echo $cnt;?>'>Edit</a>

How can i use it in button instead of A Href

Comment: Sir Dhaval please Help

Comment: I solved that Problem . I Want to ask how can I Hide the Edit button when Click on Edit button 
I Did but it will hide all the Edit buttons

Comment: it's also easy @Hammad  for specific button try eg. `jQuery(this).css("display","none");` in the `click` function

Answer (score 1):

Id cannot be used more than once, use class instead, try this code:

```
<?php foreach($result as $print): ?>
    <form method="post" class="form">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="edit-btn">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="edit-box1">
            <input class="idd" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $idd; ?>" name="status111">
            <input type="submit" value="GO" name="edit-go">
            </div>
        </tr>
    </form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('click','.edit-btn',function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.form').find('.idd').prop('readonly',false);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My Code mess up when i use this Code Sir

Answer (score 0):

1 ) all `id` convert `class`

2) Use method `removeAttr("readonly")`

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="edit-btn">Edit</a></td>
</tr>

<input class="idd" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $idd; ?>" name="status111">
```

And you can use `$(".idd").removeAttr("readonly")`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".edit-btn").click(function(){
              $(".idd").removeAttr("readonly");
               $(".idd:first").focus();

           })
       })
```

Example :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="edit-btn">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="text" class="idd" readonly>
        <input type="text" class="idd" readonly>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".edit-btn").click(function(){
              $(".idd").removeAttr("readonly");
               $(".idd:first").focus();
               
           })
       })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Hammad , Check Updated answer!

Comment: Still when i click on Edit it will focus on first row even when i click Edit of 2nd Row