# Javascript does not send POST tags in the same sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If there are more than one tag in the same sentence, only the first selected tag is being sent.

What could be the reason for this?

[Work on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/aq23sot6/)

```js
$(function(){
    $('#lbl1').one('mouseover', function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            data1 = $this.text();
        console.log(data1);
        
        $.post('/echo/html/', {
            html: 'some server response',
            data1: data1
        }, function(data){
            $this.attr('title', data).tooltip().mouseover();
        });
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/tiny/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label id="lbl1">Emre</label> and <label id="lbl1">Saracoglu</label>
```

Comment: That's because `ID`'s should be unique and not used multiple times. You should use a class for a group/collection of elements. Replace `id="lbl1"` for `class="lbl1"` and change your `jQuery` selector to `$('.lbl1').on('mouseover', function(){`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select all elements with a particular ID in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902839/how-to-select-all-elements-with-a-particular-id-in-jquery)

Comment: @NewToJS I made the change you mentioned and work but this time, same word more than one POST

Comment: What do you mean same word more than one POST? http://jsfiddle.net/aq23sot6/2/ If you only want it to execute once then use your original `.one()` rather than `.on()` as I suggested http://jsfiddle.net/aq23sot6/3/

Comment: @NewToJS Thank you for your time. If you want to answer my question, I can accept your answer.

Comment: @J.Doe You are very welcome. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments below your question:

`ID`'s should be unique and not used multiple times. You should use a `class` for a group/collection of elements.

**Solution:** Replace `id="lbl1"` for `class="lbl1"` and change your `jQuery` selector to `$('.lbl1').one('mouseover', function(){`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.lbl1').one('mouseover', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      data1 = $this.text();
    console.log(data1);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="lbl1">Emre</label> and <label class="lbl1">Saracoglu</label>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aq23sot6/3)

I hope this helps. Happy coding!